# Permission class in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

creating an assembly named Assembly1. Assembly1 contains a public method.
The global cache contains a second assembly named Assembly2. You must ensure that
the public method is only called from Assembly2. Which permission class should you use?

Comment: Sounds like a question for your teacher / tutor.

Comment: Did you look on page 354.7 yet?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to say "method can be used only by Assembly2". But, if I understood you correctly and your goal is to prevent calls from any other assembly, except for Assembly1 or Assembly2, I have an answer.

In .NET you can do this using some trick. You can make your public method `Friend` (can be used only by Assembly1). And then use [Friendly Assembly mechanism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt631696.aspx). After that you will have method that could be called only from Assembly1 or Assembly2.

Comment: What about the StrongNameIdentityPermission class?